# How $makeindex latexmk's configuration variable can be adapted to multiple .idx files (different from the source filename)?

Tags: latexmk, xindy, imakeidx

Consider a `test1.tex` file containing a (single) index that should have
a special layout and, for this, should use a specific style (say
`index.xdy`). This can be done by the following process:

1. `pdflatex test1`
2. `texindy -M index.xdy test1.idx`
3. `pdflatex test1`

which can be automated thanks to `latexmk` by:

```bash
latexmk -norc -r latexmkrc1.tex test1
```

where:

- `-norc` option just to be sure no other `latexmk` configuration file than
  `latexmkrc1.tex` is taken in account,
- `latexmkrc1.tex` file is:

  ```perl
  $makeindex = 'texindy -M index.xdy';

  $pdf_mode = 1; #$
  ```

So far, so good.

Now, consider a `test2.tex` file containing multiple (say two) indices that should have different layouts and, for this, should use different styles (say `indexA.xdy` and `indexB.xdy`). This can be done by:

1. `pdflatex test`
2. `texindy -M indexA.xdy indexA.idx`
3. `texindy -M indexB.xdy indexB.idx`
4. `pdflatex test`

Now, suppose I'd like to automate this process thanks to:

```bash
latexmk -norc -r latexmkrc2.tex test2
```

with some ad hoc `latexmkrc2.tex` configuration file.The trouble is, though the `$makeindex` configuration variable can be adapted to `.idx` different from the source filename:

```perl
$makeindex = 'texindy -M indexA.xdy %O -o indexA.ind indexA.idx'; #$
```

it cannot be specified multiple times, one for `indexA` and one for `indexB`.

**Minimal example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xindy,nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\makeindex[name=indexA,title=Index A,options=-M indexA.xdy]
\makeindex[name=indexB,title=Index B,options=-M indexB.xdy]

\begin{filecontents*}{indexA.xdy}
(markup-index :open  "~n
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
    \textsf{#1}
    \nopagebreak
  }
  ~n"
  :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
:tree)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{indexB.xdy}
(markup-index :open  "~n
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
    \textit{#1}
    \nopagebreak
  }
  ~n"
  :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
:tree)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{latexmkrc2}
$makeindex = 'texindy -M indexA.xdy %O -o indexA.ind indexA.idx'; #$

$pdf_mode = 1; #$
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Term A\index[indexA]{Term from index A}
\par
Term B\index[indexB]{Term from index B}
\printindex[indexA]
\printindex[indexB]
\end{document}
```

**Edit** My question is: How could I configure `latexmk` in order, each time `texindy` has to be run, to run it twice:

- firstly as `texindy -M indexA.xdy indexA.idx`,
- secondly as `texindy -M indexB.xdy indexB.idx`?

Comment: off-topic but why `tex` suffix in `latexmkrc1.tex`. I would not use any suffix.

Comment: @jfbu Like you, I usually not use any suffix for the `latexmkrc` files. Here, it is because their content is filled up through `filecontents*` environment (in order to make easier to test my MCE).

Comment: The general case might be difficult to solve as is. But for this, can't you use custom dependencies? I think that was how makeglossaries was added. First someone made a custom dependency setup for it, it worked fine and thus John added it to latexmk it self. Here we cannot be general, but should be enough to be able to detect these and have texindy run on then. Though I do not remember the details on how to define these, it should be noted in the latexmk manual

Comment: @daleif I'm not sure to see what you mean with "custom dependencies". But I hoped John to be warned by a question with `latexmk` tag :) I'll draw its attention in private email.

Comment: See for example: https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.HTML under advanced options, those are sometimes called custom dependencies. They require a little knowledge of pearl to write. Might be a good idea to ping John. I'm not at a pc, so cannot test.

Comment: @daleif The link is wrong: "HTML" should be "html". Try to look at it.

Comment: Strange, it should be lower case, https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html predictive text changed the html

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Sorry, my misunderstanding.  Just running latexmk on your posted code resulted in a pdf with two indices, but I hadn't noticed this was not created by the index command you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule

```
$makeindex = 'texindy -M %B.xdy %O -o %D %S'; #$
```

is what you are looking for (improved on my original version by `latexmk`s author, John Collins).  `latexmk` is careful about detecting which `idx` files are written, and the `%B` in the rule refers to the base part of the `.idx` file, rather than what one might suspect the base part of the latex file.  `%S` and `%D` are the source and destination files

Running

```
pdflatex test1
```

to extract the extra files
and then

```
latexmk -norc -r latexmkrc2.tex test1
```

on the file below saved as `test1.tex` produces

[image: Sample output]

which I believe is your desired output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xindy,nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\makeindex[name=indexA,title=Index A,options=-M indexA.xdy]
\makeindex[name=indexB,title=Index B,options=-M indexB.xdy]

\begin{filecontents*}{indexA.xdy}
(markup-index :open  "~n
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
    \textsf{#1}
    \nopagebreak
  }
  ~n"
  :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
:tree)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{indexB.xdy}
(markup-index :open  "~n
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
    \textit{#1}
    \nopagebreak
  }
  ~n"
  :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
:tree)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{latexmkrc2}
$makeindex = 'texindy -M %B.xdy %O -o %D %S'; #$

$pdf_mode = 1; #$
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Term A\index[indexA]{Term from index A}
\par
Term B\index[indexB]{Term from index B}
\printindex[indexA]
\printindex[indexB]
\end{document}
```

Comment: John Collins (the `latexmk`'s author) suggests a slight improvement of the rule you provided: `$makeindex = 'texindy -M %B.xdy %O -o %D %S';` which "lets the source and destination files be whatever `latexmk` determines they are.  Thus the second form is robust against being used in situations with different 
extensions. For example, I can use the `$makeindex` variable in a custom dependency using multiple indexes with different extensions.  See the third example in the section of the `latexmk` documentation on “Function implementing custom dependency, alternative methods”.''

Answer (score 2):

HARDCODE,not very well……

```
mv indexA.xdy indexA.idx.xdy
mv indexB.xdy indexB.idx.xdy
```

and in the latexmkrc

```
$makeindex = 'texindy -M %S.xdy %O -o %D %S'; 
# Warning：Hardcode，every [name].idx file corresponding to a [name].idx.ist
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158581)

Comment: @Sebastiano,  my english is very bad. But it's the right answer -__-, use latexmkrc to auto use the name.idx.style file...

Comment: Also mine English :-) don't worry. You can use [Deepl](https://www.deepl.com/it/translator) to traslate any words.

Comment: Indeed, what you suggest works but, as you told, isn't optimal because of the hardcoded `mv`s.