# Is it possible to hack imakeidx in order to make its different indices have different extensions?

Tags: indexing, latexmk, imakeidx

The reason of my question [How $makeindex latexmk's configuration variable can be adapted to multiple .idx files (different from the source filename)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335186/18401) was:

1. `imakeidx` can deal with multiple indices but distinguished by the corresponding files names and not files extensions,
2. `latexmk` custom dependencies and subroutines are based on extensions and not on files names,

therefore I asked if it is possible to create different `latexmk`'s `$makeindex` configuration variables for different `.idx` files distinguished by the corresponding source filename.

I earned a "Tumbleweed" badge for this (I do not know whether to laugh or cry ;) so maybe a different approach is required.

The following MWE (say `test.tex)`, to be compiled with:

1. `pdflatex test`
2. `latexmk -norc -r latexmkrc.tex test`

shows that, with the `index` package (that can deal with multiple indices but distinguished by the corresponding files extensions --- and not files names), it is possible to create `latexmk` custom dependencies and subroutines based on extensions and hence use `latexmk` to  automate the process of compiling the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\newindex{indexA}{adx}{and}{Index A}
\newindex{indexB}{bdx}{bnd}{Index B}

\begin{filecontents*}{latexmkrc}
add_cus_dep('adx', 'and', 0, 'texindyA');
sub texindyA{
    system("texindy -o \"$_[0].and\" \"$_[0].adx\"");
}

add_cus_dep('bdx', 'bnd', 0, 'texindyB');
sub texindyB{
    system("texindy -o \"$_[0].bnd\" \"$_[0].bdx\"");
}

$pdf_mode = 1; #$
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Term A\index[indexA]{Term from index A}
\par
Term B\index[indexB]{Term from index B}
\printindex[indexA]
\printindex[indexB]
\end{document}
```

For some reasons, I'm stick with `imakeidx` and hence my question is: is it possible to hack it in order to make its different indices have different extensions (in order to let this as simple as possible, `imakeidx`'s `splitindex` won't be used)?

Comment: Well naturally one can hack imakeidx (or ask egreg to expand it), but  imho if latexmk can't handle two independant xindy calls it is  a latexmk problem.

Comment: Won't the simple latexmkrc file `$makeindex = "texindy %O -o %D %S";` work with the same extensions on multiple file names?

Comment: Sorry, try using shell-escape and imakeindex will take care of the problem directly. It really has nothing to do latexmk directly.

Comment: @HerbSchulz As you noticed, `$makeindex = "texindy %O -o %D %S";` is not enough. I know the nice `shell-escape` trick with `imakeindex` but my real case is for the documentation of a LaTeX class and I'm reluctant to, in its `README`, advise users who want to compile this documentation by themselves to invoke it: by contrast, invoking `latexmk` with a short `latexmkrc`configuration file is not so harmful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is. I also suppressed the info messages issued by the `noautomatic` option, since you're using `latexmk`.

However, this also works without it (but perhaps not with Xindy, I tested it only with MakeIndex).

I'm not trying to make it work with `splitindex`. Use `morewrites` instead, if you run out of output streams.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\def\imki@finalmessage#1{}% since you're using latexmk
\def\imki@startidx#1#2{%
  \if@filesw
    \def\index{\@bsphack
      \@ifnextchar [{\@index}{\@index[\imki@jobname]}}
    \expandafter\newwrite\csname #1@idxfile\endcsname
    \immediate\openout \csname #1@idxfile\endcsname #1.#2\relax
    \typeout{Writing index file #1.#2}%
  \fi}
\xpatchcmd\imki@makeindex
  {\imki@startidx\imki@name}
  {\imki@startidx\imki@name\imki@extout}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd\imki@build
  {\imki@dokey\imki@title}
  {\imki@dokey\imki@title
   \imki@dokey\imki@extin
   \imki@dokey\imki@extout}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\imki@putindex}
  {\imki@options}
  {\space -o #1.\imki@extin\imki@options}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\imki@putindex}
  {.idx}
  {.\imki@extout}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\imki@putindex}
  {.ind}
  {.\imki@extin}
  {}{}
\def\imki@extout{idx}\def\imki@extin{ind}
\define@key{imki}{extout}{\def\imki@extout{#1}}
\define@key{imki}{extin}{\def\imki@extin{#1}}
\makeatother

\makeindex[name=indexA,extout=adx,extin=and,title={Index A}]
\makeindex[name=indexB,extout=bdx,extin=bnd,title={Index B}]


\begin{document}
Term A\index[indexA]{Term from index A}
\par
Term B\index[indexB]{Term from index B}
\printindex[indexA]
\printindex[indexB]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you think it's worth extending `imakeidx` in this respect? Otherwise, I'm not sure to understand the necessity of `noautomatic` option in case of `latexmk`use: it seems to work like a charm without it, even with `xindy` option.

Comment: What is this strange `\ddt`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I use to add `\ddt` for checking whether a patch is unsuccessful: LaTeX will stop for an undefined control sequence. I forgot to remove one of them.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Without `noautomatic` there is no need to hand jobs to `latexmk`; in particular, the rules for making the indices are irrelevant.

Comment: When you say "[w]ithout `noautomatic` there is no need to hand jobs to `latexmk`", do you mean "no need as long as you invoke `shell-escape`"?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé If you are using Xindy, yes.